# $compile throws error when compiling HTML with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation in which multiple `<a href="..">Link!</a>` elements are rendered by a third party Angular directive. I would like to add another directive to each `<a>` element, which I normally would had done with `ng-bind-html`.

If I could, I would have written it like `<a ng-href="item.Url" ng-bind-html="item.Name | highlight: $scope.searchTxt"></a>`

The only part I want to add is the `highlight` directive. My general idea is to recompile all of the elements and replace them with the new element as follows

```
angular.element('a')
    .each(function(index, val) {
        addHighlightDirective(val);
    });

var addHighlightDirective = function (el) {
    var compiledHtml = $compile("<a ng-href='" + el.href + "' ng-bind-html='" + el.innerHTML.toString() + ' | highlight: $scope.searchText' + "'></a>")($scope);
    //...
    //append to html
    //...
}
```

Suppose that the string above results to `"<a ng-href='#welcomePage' ng-bind-html='Welcome to our site! | highlight: $scope.searchText'></a>"`, `$compile` will throw the error

`script.js:XXX Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'to' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Welcome to our site! | highlight: $scope.searchText] starting at [to our site! | highlight: $scope.searchText].`

([Plnkr with error](http://plnkr.co/edit/5J9OYvnlvdUjlswz7rri))

I'm assuming that the error is somehow related to that Angular treat the string as javascript, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

How does `$compile` evaluate this, and how should I change my code for this to work?

Comment: i think you need a string around the inner html - perhaps you should transclude it?

Comment: @DanielA.White is right, the value passed to `ng-bind-html` attribute is an expression, therefore you have to wrap the string inside that expression with quotes. Try something like `ng-bind-html=''\'Welcome to our site!\' | highlight....`

Comment: Is this solved yet?